# Field length restricting not working in Android Native browser

Tags: android, validation, mobile-safari

Am facing a strange issue, In Samsung Mobile (S3 , S4 and tablets),any Text field is allowing to enter any number of characters with out restricting to the particular field length but once we go to the next field the above entered text will restricts to its actual field length.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your edittexts with adding below line to your edittext definition on your layout.

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If this is a webpage you can not do anything. It is not possible to change that.